Why parameter-based RL methods are not widely used?
Parameter-based RL methods perturb parameters of a general function approximator directly, rather than adding noise to the resulting actions. Why they haven't received the same attention and gain traction as the SOTA like SAC, TD3, PPO, etc.
Papers on the parameter-based RL algorithms:

https://people.idsia.ch/~juergen/paladyn2010.pdf
https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/1287490/file.pdf


I'd imagine that it is easier intuitively to understand the effects of adding noise to an action than it is to the weights of a deep NN. E.g., adding noise to the weights of a NN could drastically change the action, whereas adding noise to an action is much more interpretable.

what you are talking about are evolutionary strategies, also known as zero order methods
They try to approximate:
$$
\nabla_\theta \mathbb{E}^{\pi_\theta}[\sum \gamma^t r_t]
$$
and they do so by using a finite difference method, thus perturbing the weights and observing whether the loss increases or not.
The problem, is that in order to obtain the full gradient $\nabla_\theta L$ you need $|\theta|$ perturbations, therefore they poorly scale with todays big models such as neural networks
However, for certain classes of problems, they work much better than RL (particularly when the loss is very poorly condition), and they are still used

great answer, I was also looking at this the way David suggested. But your point on scalability is excellent. Can you please elaborate on your last paragraph on the loss being very poorly conditioned?

I’ve just had a thought that aren’t we also making |teta| “perturbations” when we perform backpropagation usually at every training step with neural networks in RL? I’d even go further with the fact the papers I cited suggest applying perturbation only at the beginning of an episode, so I’d say they might result in fewer perturbations than RL algorithms, say TD3. Am I missing something?

@Mika a the point are the degrees of freedom (span) of the gradient... it's a bit complex to explain it in few words, but think it this way: even if you perturb all the weights, you can either move toward this single perturbation, or away from it, so you have 1 degree of freedom... you will need $|\theta|$ perturbations (possibly orthogonal) to fully characterize the gradient

@Mika regarding the other one, it's mostly based on personal experience, where if you have a dynamical system (say a robot with many joints), you might have a ill conditioned loss (the loss of the first joint of the robot highly conditions the rest of them)... the same might happen for rewards function with long term consequences

let me see if I got it right.   In RL back propagation has only one degree of freedom in the form of the loss function and weights are “perturbed” (updated) in the direction of the loss function gradient while in the ES perturbations have much more freedom and directions they can go, right?

@Mika sorry, missunderstood your point… backprop with ppo has obviously all the degrees of freedom, but that gradient is noisy

can you please refer me to a material with more specific explanation on these methods poorly scaling with large neural networks? I am still a bit confused unless I see the math or more technical explanation. Thanks

@Mika I'd suggest you to give a look at "Deep RL Bootcamp Lecture 8 Derivative Free Methods" on youtube
